# Turning off password hashing in Authcomponent Cake PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, hash

I am trying to put login screen in my application.
Have got the model up and running.

Now according to CakePHP 3.x cookbook i have added the following into my code.

```
// In src/Controller/AppController.php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
class AppController extends Controller
{
public function initialize()
{
$this->loadComponent('Flash');
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
'authenticate' => [
'Form' => [
'fields' => [
'username' => 'email',
'password' => 'password'
]
]
],
'loginAction' => [
'controller' => 'Users',
'action' => 'login'
]
]);
// Allow the display action so our pages controller
// continues to work.
$this->Auth->allow(['display']);
}
}
```

// In src/Controller/UsersController.php

```
public function login()
{
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
if ($user) {
$this->Auth->setUser($user);
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}
$this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
}
}
```

In login.ctp

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I got the screen up and running.
But then found out that the passwords needs to hashed. Which is not there in mysql database. I hashed the password with sha1 in my db.
But found that by default cakephp uses bcrypt, so configured it with weak "sha1" password.

But then there is a salt value added to the password which is making both the passwords mismatch. How do i solve this ?

I am also fine with turning of the hashing feature, found some links in SO about that. But none are for cake php 3x. 
In the documentation, its mentioned turn off the auth component if i don't want to use the hashing feature. But i would like to use it.

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: How about following the manual [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) which also explains how to create new users with properly hashed passwords.

Comment: `Member for 5 years, 2 months` Please format the code in your question.

Comment: @ADmad thanks for the reply...yes that worked...but was looking for creating password without hash...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your problem will definitely will be solved:-

```
// src/Model/Entity/User.php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{

    // Make all fields mass assignable for now.
    protected $_accessible = ['*' => true];


    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...yes that worked...but was looking for creating password without hash...